# Apache redirect <ip>/<path> to <localhost>:<other port>

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I'm hosting an apache web server for a few years. This is just for some side project at work and I don't have a domain. We just use the public ip wich works great. 
But now I did install an other web based tool on the server (Grafana) and that works fine on http://123.456.78.9:3000

But our firewall at work gives issues because we reach it via a non-standard port.

I was wondering if I could configure apache to redirect all traffic from http://123.456.78.9/grafana to localhost:3000

That way the Grafana web-based tool could be reached via the default port 80

I did found a lot of information about virtual hosts, but all of those use a domain name, which I don't have.

Or any other options would be appreciated a lot!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does not work? This is a pretty basic redirect, you just don't have a domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest reading through the [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/behind_proxy/).

While the problem of proxying to different backends based on path isn't new, it somewhat died with the introduction of SNI and virtual hosts which eliminated the need for a 1-1 relation between IP and domain.

While you don't have a DNS, you can still use domains by adding them to your `/etc/hosts`. Your browser will hapilly send the SNI and your server will be able to differentiate on domain.

If you'd rather go the URL way, you need to configure every single service you host to change their root URL, which for Grafana looks like:

```
[server]
domain = foo.bar
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana/
```

And then proxy the `/grafana` to the appropriate backend.

If you don't change the root URL in Grafana, the Grafan backend will try to find `/grafana` while it expects `/` so you will hit a lot of 404.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried the grafana documentation before, but didn't know what to change in Apache. At least I know what to look for!

Answer (score 0):

you may create an empty webpage(index.php) under your desired virtualhost directory and redirect to any other address you want to.
just need to put the line below in your index.php, and modify the destination address.

following is the PHP code for this purpose.

> < ?php header("Location: http://www.redirect.to.url.com/"); ?>

Comment: Thanks, this will redirect the browser to the old URL (ip:port), but from that moment on the firewall will block the traffic. This was already suggested bij our IT. So I know it won't work for my specific problem. :)